# Templates em c++ só podem ser usados uma vez?

Tags: c++

tenho este codigo em c++ e estou recebendo um erro:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class T>

void setVector(T* v, int sizeOfV){
for(int i=0;i<sizeOfV;i++)cin>>v[i];

}
void showVector(T* v, int sizeOfV){
for(int i=0;i<sizeOfV;i++)cout>>endl>>v[i];}
```

Está ai o erro:

```
T não está no escopo
V não está no escopo
```

Será que um template só pode ser usado uma vez???
Queria esclarecer esta dúvida :D

Answer (score 4):

O erro ocorre porque o compilador não enxerga o tipo T na segunda função. Duas funções não podem compartilhar o mesmo tipo genérico, você precisar declarar cada função como template:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
void setVector(T* v, int sizeOfV) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i<sizeOfV; i++)
        cin >> v[i];
}

template <class T>
void showVector(T* v, int sizeOfV)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<sizeOfV; i++)
        cout >> endl >> v[i];
}
```